# Edit custom button in SharePoint Ribbon

Tags: .net, button, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-designer

There is an custom button present in my team SharePoint site. I want to edit the button now but not able to find the option to do so.

Could you please help me to edit custom button present in the files ribbon in SharePoint 2013 using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Is this button only present when on a certain list?

Comment: yes it is the only Custom button present in that library

Answer (score 0):

If the button is present with a certain list, and was originally made in SharePoint Designer, you will find it under "Custom Actions" on the List page.

See the bottom of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx) for more info on Custom Actions in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: It is created with the help of the  **Custom Action** in the SharePoint Designer. But i am not able to edit this button now. All the options like **Display From Ribbon**, **Edit From Ribbon**,**New From Ribbon** are redirecting to the same window. But nothing help me to edit the custom button

Comment: Redirecting to same window (Create Custom Action Window)

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot in your question (with sensitive information blacked out) that may be helpful. Another thing I would do is check to see if your user permissions are the same as whoever first created it.